# Setup is "unresponsive" at startup if I compile it with compression

Tags: inno-setup

The thing is: I have embedded music into the installer using the Bass Audio Library and when I compile without compression, the installer works fine. If compiled with compression, it just freezes and "does not respond".

```
[Code]

// Скрипт на время установки.
function GetTickCount: DWORD;
  external 'GetTickCount@kernel32.dll stdcall';

var
  StartTick: DWORD;
  PercentLabel: TNewStaticText;
  ElapsedLabel: TNewStaticText;
  RemainingLabel: TNewStaticText;

function TicksToStr(Value: DWORD): string;
var
  I: DWORD;
  Hours, Minutes, Seconds: Integer;
begin
  I := Value div 1000;
  Seconds := I mod 60;
  I := I div 60;
  Minutes := I mod 60;
  I := I div 60;
  Hours := I mod 24;
  Result := Format('%.2d:%.2d:%.2d', [Hours, Minutes, Seconds]);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  PercentLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  PercentLabel.Parent := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Parent;
  PercentLabel.Left := 0;
  PercentLabel.Top := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Top +
    WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Height + 12;

  ElapsedLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  ElapsedLabel.Parent := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Parent;
  ElapsedLabel.Left := 0;
  ElapsedLabel.Top := PercentLabel.Top + PercentLabel.Height + 4;

  RemainingLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  RemainingLabel.Parent := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Parent;
  RemainingLabel.Left := 0;
  RemainingLabel.Top := ElapsedLabel.Top + ElapsedLabel.Height + 4;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpInstalling then
    StartTick := GetTickCount;
end;

procedure CancelButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer; var Cancel, Confirm: Boolean);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpInstalling then
  begin
    Cancel := False;
    if ExitSetupMsgBox then
    begin
      Cancel := True;
      Confirm := False;
      PercentLabel.Visible := False;
      ElapsedLabel.Visible := False;
      RemainingLabel.Visible := False;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure CurInstallProgressChanged(CurProgress, MaxProgress: Integer);
var
  CurTick: DWORD;
begin
  CurTick := GetTickCount;
  PercentLabel.Caption :=
    Format('Готово: %.2f %%', [(CurProgress * 100.0) / MaxProgress]);
  ElapsedLabel.Caption := 
    Format('Прошедшее время: %s', [TicksToStr(CurTick - StartTick)]);
  if CurProgress > 0 then
  begin
    RemainingLabel.Caption :=
      Format('Оставшееся время: %s', [TicksToStr(
        ((CurTick - StartTick) / CurProgress) * (MaxProgress - CurProgress))]);
  end;
end;

// Скрипт на время удаления.
function SetTimer(hWnd: longword; nIDEvent, uElapse: LongWord;
  lpTimerFunc: LongWord): LongWord; external 'SetTimer@user32.dll stdcall';
function GetTickCount2: DWORD;
  external 'GetTickCount@kernel32.dll stdcall';

var
  UninstallStartTick: DWORD;
  UninstallPercentLabel: TNewStaticText;
  UninstallElapsedLabel: TNewStaticText;
  UninstallRemainingLabel: TNewStaticText;

function TicksToStr2(Value: DWORD): string;
var
  I: DWORD;
  Hours, Minutes, Seconds: Integer;
begin
  I := Value div 1000;
  Seconds := I mod 60;
  I := I div 60;
  Minutes := I mod 60;
  I := I div 60;
  Hours := I mod 24;
  Result := Format('%.2d:%.2d:%.2d', [Hours, Minutes, Seconds]);
end;

procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
begin
  if CurUninstallStep = usUninstall then
  begin
    UninstallStartTick := GetTickCount;
  end;
end;

procedure UninstallTimerProc(
  h: LongWord; AMsg: LongWord; IdEvent: LongWord; dwTime: LongWord);
var
  CurTick: DWORD;
  CurProgress: Integer;
  MaxProgress: Integer;
begin
  MaxProgress := UninstallProgressForm.ProgressBar.Max;
  CurProgress := UninstallProgressForm.ProgressBar.Position;

  if MaxProgress > 0 then
  begin
    CurTick := GetTickCount;
    UninstallPercentLabel.Caption :=
      Format('Готово: %.2f %%', [(CurProgress * 100.0) / MaxProgress]);
    UninstallElapsedLabel.Caption := 
      Format('Прошедшее время: %s', [TicksToStr(CurTick - UninstallStartTick)]);
    if CurProgress > 0 then
    begin
      UninstallRemainingLabel.Caption :=
        Format('Оставшееся время: %s', [TicksToStr(
          ((CurTick - UninstallStartTick) / CurProgress) *
           (MaxProgress - CurProgress))]);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeUninstallProgressForm();
begin
  UninstallPercentLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
  UninstallPercentLabel.Parent := UninstallProgressForm.ProgressBar.Parent;
  UninstallPercentLabel.Left := UninstallProgressForm.ProgressBar.Left;
  UninstallPercentLabel.Top := UninstallProgressForm.ProgressBar.Top +
    UninstallProgressForm.ProgressBar.Height + ScaleY(12);

  UninstallElapsedLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
  UninstallElapsedLabel.Parent := UninstallProgressForm.ProgressBar.Parent;
  UninstallElapsedLabel.Left := UninstallPercentLabel.Left;
  UninstallElapsedLabel.Top :=
    UninstallPercentLabel.Top + UninstallPercentLabel.Height + ScaleY(4);

  UninstallRemainingLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
  UninstallRemainingLabel.Parent := UninstallProgressForm.ProgressBar.Parent;
  UninstallRemainingLabel.Left := UninstallPercentLabel.Left;
  UninstallRemainingLabel.Top :=
    UninstallElapsedLabel.Top + UninstallElapsedLabel.Height + ScaleY(4);

  SetTimer(0, 0, 100, CreateCallback(@UninstallTimerProc)); { every 100 ms }
end;

// Скрипт на проигрывание музыки и для кнопок.
const
  BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP = 4;
  BASS_ACTIVE_STOPPED = 0;
  BASS_ACTIVE_PLAYING = 1;
  BASS_ACTIVE_STALLED = 2;
  BASS_ACTIVE_PAUSED  = 3;
  BASS_UNICODE = $80000000;
  BASS_CONFIG_GVOL_STREAM = 5;
const
  #ifndef UNICODE
    EncodingFlag = 0;
  #else
    EncodingFlag = BASS_UNICODE;
  #endif
type
  HSTREAM = DWORD;

function BASS_Init(device: LongInt; freq, flags: DWORD;
  win: HWND; clsid: Cardinal): Boolean;
  external 'BASS_Init@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_StreamCreateFile(mem: Boolean; f: string; offset1: DWORD;
  offset2: DWORD; length1: DWORD; length2: DWORD; flags: DWORD): HSTREAM;
  external 'BASS_StreamCreateFile@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_ChannelPlay(handle: DWORD; restart: Boolean): Boolean;
  external 'BASS_ChannelPlay@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_ChannelPause(handle: DWORD): Boolean;
  external 'BASS_ChannelPause@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_SetConfig(option: DWORD; value: DWORD ): Boolean;
  external 'BASS_SetConfig@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_ChannelIsActive(handle: DWORD): DWORD;
  external 'BASS_ChannelIsActive@files:bass.dll stdcall';

var
  SoundStream: HSTREAM;
  PauseResumePlayButton: TNewButton;
  StopButton: TNewButton;

procedure ResumeButtonClick(Sender: TObject); forward;

procedure PauseButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if BASS_ChannelPause(SoundStream) then
  begin
    PauseResumePlayButton.Caption := 'Возобновить';
    PauseResumePlayButton.OnClick := @ResumeButtonClick;
  end;
end;  

procedure ResumeButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if BASS_ChannelPlay(SoundStream, False) then
  begin
    PauseResumePlayButton.Caption := 'Пауза';
    PauseResumePlayButton.OnClick := @PauseButtonClick;
  end;
end;  

procedure PlayButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if BASS_ChannelPlay(SoundStream, True) then
  begin
    PauseResumePlayButton.Caption := 'Пауза';
    PauseResumePlayButton.OnClick := @PauseButtonClick;
  end;
end;  

procedure StopButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (BASS_ChannelIsActive(SoundStream) = BASS_ACTIVE_PAUSED) or
     BASS_ChannelPause(SoundStream) then
  begin
    PauseResumePlayButton.Caption := 'Плей';
    PauseResumePlayButton.OnClick := @PlayButtonClick;
  end;
end;  

<event('InitializeWizard')>
procedure InitializeWizard2();
begin
  if BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0, 0, 0) then
  begin
    ExtractTemporaryFile('music.mp3');
    SoundStream :=
      BASS_StreamCreateFile(
        False, ExpandConstant('{tmp}\music.mp3'), 0, 0, 0, 0,
        EncodingFlag or BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP);

    if SoundStream <> 0 then
    begin
      BASS_SetConfig(BASS_CONFIG_GVOL_STREAM, 2500);

      if BASS_ChannelPlay(SoundStream, False) then
      begin
        StopButton := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
        StopButton.Parent := WizardForm;
        StopButton.Left :=
          WizardForm.ClientWidth -
          WizardForm.CancelButton.Left -  WizardForm.CancelButton.Width;
        StopButton.Top := WizardForm.CancelButton.Top;
        StopButton.Width :=  WizardForm.CancelButton.Width;
        StopButton.Height := WizardForm.CancelButton.Height;
        StopButton.Caption := 'Стоп';
        StopButton.OnClick := @StopButtonClick;

        PauseResumePlayButton := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
        PauseResumePlayButton.Parent := WizardForm;
        PauseResumePlayButton.Left :=
          WizardForm.ClientWidth -
          WizardForm.NextButton.Left -  WizardForm.NextButton.Width;
        PauseResumePlayButton.Top := WizardForm.CancelButton.Top;
        PauseResumePlayButton.Width :=  WizardForm.CancelButton.Width;
        PauseResumePlayButton.Height := WizardForm.CancelButton.Height;
        PauseResumePlayButton.Caption := 'Пауза';
        PauseResumePlayButton.OnClick := @PauseButtonClick;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Maybe it's all about code optimization, but I'm not a programmer, unfortunately. Therefore, I hope for your help.

Comment: Hmm, can you tell me what else specifically I can give? I don't even know exactly what the problem might be...

Perhaps the problem is that my installer weighs several gigabytes. But without compression, it weighed more, and started without problems. And with compression, it freezes in Windows processes.

Comment: A minimal reproducible example means that you would update your question with a sample Inno Setup script that contains only the minimal amount of code needed to reproduce the problem. Read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more information.

Comment: What's the compression algorithm you chose and what's the machine specification?  Decompression requires enough system resources (CPU time and memory, as well as fast enough hard disks), so you shouldn't expect no pain on slow machines.

Comment: @LexLi, Here are the characteristics of my laptop:
Intel Pentium B970, 2 core 2.3GHz.
8GB RAM
NVIDIA GeForce 610M 1GB

Now I tried to compile with compression without using a script for music and everything works, the installer starts. Apparently, the problem is just in the Bass Audio Library.

Here is the compression method I use:
https://ibb.co/3Cmc1gN

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, Just try using the Bass Audio Library code that I left in the post. Set the compression as in the screenshot from my previous comment, and the problem will be reproduced.

Comment: Yes, it helped! Thank you all very much!